# MySQL If else in SELECT performance

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We are using IF conditions in SELECT statement like given below

```
IF(PG_COMPANY IS NULL,'N/A', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tpgm.PG_COMPANY, 'COMPANY1', '') , 'COMPANY2', '') , 'COMPANY3', '') ) AS 'COMPANY_NAME'
```

This works properly where output is upto 1 million records.
beyond that it starts giving performance issue.

Is there any way to reduce this performance issue. or are  there any other work around available ?

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: The case when the output expression evaluation produces the performance issue is rare enough. Optimize source rows selection for output building.

Comment: The query works properly after removing if clause from SELECT statement. It gives quick results for 10 million+ records.